# Thevenin Resistance query

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, dc, resistance, thevenin

I have an amplifier model circuit where I've determined the load (speaker) voltage (using its peak power output and its resistance) and measured the open-circuit voltage.

How can I work out the Thevenin resistance?

I am familiar with finding Rth when condensing a standard linear circuit but struggle to work backwards.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: $$R_{TH} = R_L \left( \frac{V_{OPEN}}{V_{LOAD}}-1\right)$$ Where V_open is a  open-circuit voltage and V_laod is an output voltage with the load connected.

Comment: @G36 Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$$R_{TH} = R_L \left( \frac{V_{OPEN}}{V_{LOAD}}-1\right)$$

Where V_open is the open-circuit voltage and V_load is an output voltage with the load connected.

Provided by user G36.